# How to get the last slice of a Python list when iterating over consecutive slices at the end of the list

Tags: python, list, slice

I might be having a brain-freeze here but how do you iterate over the last n slices of length d of a list of indeterminate length and still get the last slice `[-d:]`?

What I tried:

```
In [37]: x = list(range(100))                                                 

In [38]: window = 15                                                          

In [39]: d = window // 3                                                      

In [40]: for i in range(0, window, d): 
    ...:     print(i, x[-i-d:-i]) 
    ...:
```

Output:

```
0 []
5 [90, 91, 92, 93, 94]
10 [85, 86, 87, 88, 89]
```

What I want:

```
0 [95, 96, 97, 98, 99]
5 [90, 91, 92, 93, 94]
10 [85, 86, 87, 88, 89]
```

The problem of course, is that in the last iteration, `-i` is zero not `None`.  I'm sure there's an easier way than this:

```
In [42]: for i in range(0, window, d): 
    ...:     if i == 0: 
    ...:         print(i, x[-i-d:]) 
    ...:     else: 
    ...:         print(i, x[-i-d:-i]) 
    ...:
```

or this:

```
In [44]: import numpy as np                                                   

In [45]: np.array(x)[-window:].reshape((3,-1))                                
Out[45]: 
array([[85, 86, 87, 88, 89],
       [90, 91, 92, 93, 94],
       [95, 96, 97, 98, 99]])
```

Comment: Hum it seems you write a mistake, output and expected output are same, please edit ;)

Comment: Thanks @azro.  I fixed it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As `bool(0)` is `False` you can use to take `None` for other bound, and you'll get all the slice :

```
for i in range(0, window, d):
    print(i, x[-i - d:-i or None])

0 [95, 96, 97, 98, 99]
5 [90, 91, 92, 93, 94]
10 [85, 86, 87, 88, 89]
```

Comment: Very nice.  Thanks.